# How can I open a file in VIM in readonly mode if it already has a swapfile?

Tags: files, vim, swap

When I use the command `:e filename` to open a file and this file is already opened by another vim instance, I get a prompt asking me if I want to open the file in *read-only mode*, edit anyway, recover, exit or abort.

When I try `:silent! e filename` what happens is that vim seems to have hanged. But it is indeed asking me what to do with the swapfile, just I can't see it because I told it to be silent.

Is there any command where I can tell it to open the file in *read-only mode* **if** the file can't be opened in write mode and without requiring user interaction? (I want to integrate this into a macro to jump/open files).

Answer (score 7):

If you have **vim >= 7** (I think) you can use `autocmd` with an event `SwapExists`. There you can do all from very simple things to very complicated.
Here is a simple example to put in your ~/.vimrc:

```
autocmd SwapExists * let v:swapchoice = "o"
```

If a swap file exists, this event will be triggered. The autocmd above will simply open the file in read only mode.
If `v:swapchoice` gets a value in an autocmd it will **not** prompt you what you want to do. The values you can use is listed here [v:swapchoice](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#v%3aswapchoice).
For a very advanced autocmd see here: [editexisting.vim](https://github.com/svintus/vim-editexisting/blob/master/plugin/editexisting.vim)
The script there can already be on your server from the installation of vim, search for `editexisting.vim`.

Answer (score 5):

I have a script in my `.vimrc` which does exactly this. However it does so for all files opened which has a swp file. Not sure if you always want this behavior. Maybe you can tweak it to fit your needs in the macro you are writing.

To open ro if a swp file is present, put this in your `.vimrc`:

```
func CheckSwap()
  swapname
  if v:statusmsg =~ '\.sw[^p]$'
    set ro
  endif
endfunc

if &swf
  set shm+=A
  au BufReadPre * call CheckSwap()
endif
```

I got this script from [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_same_file_read-only_in_second_Vim), there is a more advanced example there as well which might be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

The command `view` in RHEL and ubuntu opens vim in readonly mode, though you can override the readonly mode by using `:w!`.

Comment: Yes, I would like to preserve the *writeability* if possible, though. Unfortunately reading through the swap-file help it seems that detecting if a swap file exists is not reliable either.